# How to create a dynamic expression in the filter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In **Scala/Spark** application I have 2 variables (x1 and x2). They are dynamic and in some cases one of them can be null. In other words there can be 3 option:

```
1) x1=2505; x2=6895;
2) x1=2505; x2=null;
3) x1=null; x2=6895;
```

Depending on the value of the variables, I need to generate different expression in the `.filter` method. How to make it correctly?

At the moment I'm using the following not elegant design:

```
if(x1 != null && x2 != null)
{
    val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("path").filter(col("_x1") == x1 && col("_x2") == x2)
}
else if(x1 != null && x2 == null)
{
    val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("path").filter(col("_x1")==x1)
}
else if (x1 == null && x2 != null){
    val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("path").filter(col("_x2")==x2)
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with it? I would give the filter-expression as return value of the if-else-block. Then 1 line to read the dataframe using the dynamically generated filter

Answer (score 2):

I would first define the filter depending on x1 and x2, then read the dataframe :

```
val filter = (x1,x2) match {
  case _ if(x1==null && x2!=null) => col("_x2")===x2
  case _ if(x1!=null && x2==null) => col("_x1")===x1
  case _ if(x1!=null && x2!=null) => col("_x1")===x1 and col("_x2")===x2
}

val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("path").filter(filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much more elegant this is, but if you replace the `null`-able values with `Option[T]`, then you can have your code work with an arbitrary number of optional filters using the way `flatMap` treats `Option[_]`:

```
def makeFilter[T](filterValues: (String, Option[T])*) = {
  def makeCol(colName: String, v: Option[T]) = v match {
    case Some(x) => Some(col(colName) === x)
    case None => None
  }
  filterValues.flatMap { case (col, v) => makeCol(col, v) }.foldLeft(expr("true"))(_ && _)
}
```

Here is how it works:

```
scala> makeFilter("_x1" -> Some(2505), "_x2" -> Some(6895))
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((true AND (_x1 = 2505)) AND (_x2 = 6895))
scala> makeFilter("_x1" -> Some(2505), "_x2" -> None)
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (true AND (_x1 = 2505))
scala> makeFilter("_x1" -> None, "_x2" -> Some(6895))
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (true AND (_x2 = 6895))
scala> makeFilter()
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = true
scala> makeFilter("_x1" -> Some(100), "_x2" -> None, "_x3" -> Some(444))
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = ((true AND (_x1 = 100)) AND (_x3 = 444))
```

Catalist will optimise the `true AND X` to just `X`.

Use like this:

```
val df = spark
  .read
   .option("delimiter", "|")
   .csv("path")
   .filter(makeFilter("_x1" -> x1, "_x2" -> x2))
```